# How to make separate config file for sms sending

Tags: api, codeigniter, sms

I have done a sms sending code in codeigniter. It is worked successfully. But actually i want to make a config file so that i will not write the username, password, senderid on each page.

Here is my code below. First i have done a library file for sms sending.

Sms.php

```
<?php
class SMS
{
    function SendSMS($url)
    {
        if(function_exists('curl_init'))
        {
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            $timeout = 60; 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch); 
            if($data === FALSE){ 
                throw new Exception(curl_errno($ch)); 
            } 
            curl_close($ch); 
            return $data;       
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Again for sms sending i am writting code in each controller something like this.

```
$sms_username = "GAPSMS";
$sms_password = "GAPSMS";
$sms_senderid = "GAPSMS";
$sms_mobile = $mobile;
$sms_message  = urlencode('Your One Time Password for transaction is: '.$otp);
$sms_api = "http://sendsms.sandeshwala.com/API/WebSMS/Http/v1.0a/index.php?username=$sms_username&password=$sms_password&sender=$sms_senderid&to=$sms_mobile&message=$sms_message&reqid=1&format={json|text}";
$this->sms->SendSMS($sms_api);
```

This much below code i want to write in a config file in such a way so that i can write this once and then can use in every controller to send sms.

```
$sms_username = "GAPSMS";
$sms_password = "GAPSMS";
$sms_senderid = "GAPSMS";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATED

In CodeIgniter, libraries can have their own configuration file. Let's change your library a bit:

```
<?php
class Sms
{
    private $_username = 'GAPSMS'; // default value
    private $_password = 'GAPSMS'; // default value
    private $_senderid = 'GAPSMS'; // default value

    /**
     * Class constructor so the config
     * file is loaded.
     */
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        if ( ! empty($config))
        {
            foreach ($config as $key => $val)
            {
                $this->{"_".$key} = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    function send($mobile, $message)
    {
        if(function_exists('curl_init'))
        {
            $url = 'http://sendsms.sandeshwala.com/API/WebSMS/Http/v1.0a/index.php?username='.$this->_username.'&password='.$this->_password.'&sender='.$this->_senderid.'&to='.$mobile.'&message='.$message.'&reqid=1&format={json|text}';
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            $timeout = 60; 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch); 
            if($data === FALSE){ 
                throw new Exception(curl_errno($ch)); 
            } 
            curl_close($ch); 
            return $data;       
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then go create the config file `application/config/sms.php` inside which you put:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['username'] = 'GAPSMS';
$config['password'] = 'GAPSMS';
$config['senderid'] = 'GAPSMS';
// End of file.
```

Now whenever the library is loaded, and config file is loaded as well as values are set, everything should work just fine. And the rest of the code would be:

```
// Load the library and simply pass mobile number and message.
$this->load->library('sms');
$data = $this->sms->send('0123456789', 'Hello, this is the message');
```

Comment: Why you have put username, password, and senderid on both library and config files.

Comment: To have a fallback values in case the config files is missing, deleted or username, password and senderid are not present.

Comment: some stupid made negative mark to that question. that means when anyone need this kind of answer they will not go for this though it is already have negative mark. So can you please provide a vote to the question. So that others also will get the benefit of that answer.